# ¿Como pedir ayuda para una tarea?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, revisión-de-pregunta, preguntas

Tengo un problema en un ejercicio que me entregaron, pero no sé cómo realizar estas preguntas en el sitio o si están permitidas. Tengo parte de mi trabajo hecho pero una duda me detiene. No sé bajo qué etiqueta sería correcto publicar este tipo de dudas.

Comment: Te sugiero que edites esta pregunta y agregues info de esa tarea para que podamos entender mejor de que se trata y ayudarte a formular las preguntas correctas en el sitio. Salu2

Comment: @Luiggi: Estoy revisando las etiquetas de preguntas sobre tareas/trabajos escolares y ejercicios. En este pregunta se incluyó la etiqueta revisión de pregunta pero el wiki menciona que es para preguntas ya realizadas y en este caso la pregunta no ha había sido publicada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creo que es irrelevante que sea una tarea, mientras sea una buena pregunta en el presente y en el futuro, que te ayude a ti a resolver un problema y a otros usuarios en el futuro. Las etiquetas deben estar relacionadas con el lenguaje de programación o el tema de tu pregunta, es decir que sea tarea o no, no es el tema, por lo tanto, ***"tarea"* no debe ser una etiqueta**.

Para esto hay varías guías:

- Como elaborar una buena pregunta: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask).
- Cómo crear un ejemplo completo, mínimo y verificable: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.
- ¿Qué son las etiquetas, y cómo debo usarlas?: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging.

Elabora una buena pregunta y que no te preocupe que sea una tarea. Que eso no te detenga.

Answer (score 7):

Añadiendo a la respuesta de @toledano, la cual está muy completa, voy a intentar poner los puntos que para mí son los más importantes.

El primero y el mejor de todos, has realizado una pregunta anterior sobre si se podía o no realizar una pregunta por ser un ejercicio que te mandaron. Realmente para eso está el sitio, para gente que tiene problemas con temas relacionados con la programación ya sea en el ámbito del colegio, en su trabajo o en algún proyecto profesional. No importa dónde hayas encontrado el problema que te ha impedido seguir, el fin es el mismo para todos los casos, resolver ese error que te "está matando la cabeza".

Una vez aclarado esto, lo que sería imprescindible para añadir a tu pregunta desde mi punto de vista sería:

- Un enunciado (no hace falta que sea el del ejercicio en cuestión) indicando lo que deseas hacer y dónde estás fallando.
- **Simplifica al máximo tu código**. Muchas veces es difícil preguntar sobre algo concreto de un proyecto muy grande. Por ello, te recomiendo que no copies y pegues todo tu código ya que seguramente tu pregunta será ignorada. Si consigues localizar dónde te da el error y crear un ejemplo sencillo en el que también de ese error sería lo más ideal.
- Muestra los datos que estás utilizando (entrada) y los datos que tiene que devolver (salida). Si no aceptas datos de entrada, muestra los pasos que estás siguiendo para la ejecución de tu programa.
- Si el código te está fallando con algún tipo de error deja bien claro cual es el error y a ser posible en que línea te está lanzando el error. Muchas veces viene indicada en el mensaje de error o en el compilador.
- Haz un título de la pregunta que sea relevante y coherente con el contenido. No pongas "Este ejercicio no funciona" o "La aplicación se me cierra y no se porque". Intenta explicar cual es el error en tu pregunta de una forma breve pero que enseguida pueda ser interpretada por el resto de usuarios en caso de que hayan tenido el mismo error.
- En cuanto a las etiquetas no tienes que usar ninguna etiqueta especial por ser una "tarea escolar", de hecho, como he comentado antes, no tiene relevancia alguna que sea tarea escolar o del trabajo. Usa las etiquetas coherentes al contenido de la pregunta. Por ejemplo, si estás hablando sobre un ejercicio de un problema en [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) no tiene sentido que etiquetes la pregunta con [ios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios). Tampoco abuses de las etiquetas y usa realmente las que se ciñan a la resolución o al contexto del problema.

En resumen:

- Muestra el esfuerzo realizado.
- Define bien tu problema. Intenta ser lo más claro posible y reducir al máximo el código que vayas a mostrar (muestra solamente lo relevante).
- Indica bien lo que has realizado y dónde te has atascado/ te está lanzado el error.

Con estas pautas en mente (creo que no me dejo ninguna de las más importantes) no tendrás ningún problema en desarrollar una buena pregunta y que sea bien aceptada por la comunidad, independientemente de si es una tarea escolar o un problema que has tenido en tu proyecto personal.

Por supuesto, nunca pongas el enunciado solo sin mostrar nada de lo que has realizado hasta el momento. Y no es simplemente porque lo puedas postear o no aquí, si no porque si no prácticas primero, nunca podrás llegar realmente a aprender programación.

Comment: Otra recomendación: tampoco muestres solo un fragmento de código intentando que nosotros descifremos cuál es el problema.

Comment: Hola @LuiggiMendoza. Muchas gracias por la recomendación, sin embargo, cuando hablo de "_lo que sería imprescindible para añadir a tu pregunta_" daba por supuesto que todas las opciones que se planteaban eran para introducir en la pregunta. Por supuesto la primera recomendación es poner un enunciado de lo que se necesita y el segundo punto minimizar el código al máximo. Además, en el apartado de resumen también hago bastante incapie en que explique bien su problema.