# Mejoremos nuestras preguntas y respuestas

Tags: discusión

Buenos días comunidad, soy nuevo en la StackOverflow, debo decir, que me  he llevado muchas satisfacciones como decepciones, por lo dificil que resulta entender muchas preguntas y respuestas. Por ello sugiero los siguiente:

**EN LAS PREGUNTAS**

1. Separe su pregunta en tres fases:

   **FASE 01: MI CASO:**
   A. Exponga lo que estás haciendo, si es posible **enumere en items** los puntos relevantes.
   B. Coloque el **código completo** para que este pueda ser analizado y de esa manera dar una respuesta más acertada.
   C. Coloque **comentarios** en el código si fuera necesario (en la linea que necesitas ayuda).
   D. Coloque el **nombre de los archivos** del cual estás colocando el código.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
   E. Coloque **Capturas de pantalla** de logs o pantallas de los errores.

**FASE 02: LO QUE FUNCIONA**
Usa esta sección para detallar lo que ya funciona correctamente tu código, asi el que responde evitará darte soluciones que no necesitas, si es posible **enuméralos** en items

**FASE 03: LO QUE QUIERO**
Detalla que quieres lograr exactamente con las respuestas, su es posible **enuméralos**

**EJEMPLO**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EN LAS RESPUESTAS**

**Usar el método TUTORIAL.**
1. Enumere los pasos a seguir
2. Use capturas en las secciones donde se indiquen lugares.
3. En las modificaciones de código, use **ANTES** y **DESPUES** para indicar como está y como debería estar.
4. Indique el nombre del archivo donde se debe hacer la modificación
5. Explique el código que estás colocando.
6. De ser un ejemplo que lo haz aplicado y te funciona, pon capturas como prueba de que si funciona.
7. **EVITE COPIAR Y PEGAR** sin comprobar el código porque esto genera confusiones.
8. Coloque fuentes(links) de tus respuestas si fuera el caso, especialmente cuando las respuestas son parte de un ejemplo más completo para que pueda ser revisado.

> Espero tomemos estas sugerencias para lograr una buena colaboración.

Comment: Un fromato tan marcado no creo que sea necesario. Lo importante es que tenga todo lo necesario para su resolucion: Explicacion, codigo, errores o problemas, intentos y ejemplos. Y sobre todo una vez que acabas de redactar una pregunta leerla de nuevo pero fingiendo que eres alguien ajeno a tu proyecto. Mucha gente no explica cosas que considera obvias pero que si no eres el autor no lo son tanto .

Comment: Hola Jorny y bienvenido a [so.es]. Qué bueno que sugieras formas de hacerlo más entendible. De hecho, a esto se le suele llamar [mcve] y es altamente recomendable pedírselo a quien formula preguntas.

Comment: Gracias, espero lo tomemos como punto de partida para lograr un estádar ;)

Comment: El estandar es este [mcve]. Si hay un punto de partida __debería__ ser el MCVE.

Comment: No sale el [mcve] =) Es [mcve](/help/mcve)

Comment: @toledano jeje, es que este [magic-link](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1059/83) solo funciona en [main], no en Meta :)

Answer (score 2):

En primer lugar, gracias por tu aportación para mejorar el sitio. Definitivamente el publicar buenas preguntas y respuestas es un tema toral de esta comunidad.

Considero que en una propuesta de este tipo es importante revisar la documentación existente, partiendo de la ayuda. Por ejemplo tenemos varios artículo sobre cómo realizar preguntas, de las cuáles el básico es [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

De forma similar, en cuanto a las respuesta está [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

En la propuesta sería bueno hacer mención si el artículo es claro o no y si la recomendación es para mejorar el artículo o bien si se trata de un complemento, por ejemplo, para casos sobre tipo de preguntas/respuestas.

En [FAQ para sitios de Stack Exchange](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1378/faq-para-sitios-de-stack-exchange) se encuentra preguntas/respuestas categorizadas en el que que sería útil incluir más sobre cómo escribir buenas preguntas y/o respuestas para lo cual podría ser de utilidad revisar los hilos sobre el tema en inglés algunos de los cuáles están listados en [¿Sabes inglés, quieres aportar a la comunidad de SOes y no sabes cómo? ¡Traduce un FAQ!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1380/sabes-ingl%C3%A9s-quieres-aportar-a-la-comunidad-de-soes-y-no-sabes-c%C3%B3mo-traduce)

Preguntas relacionadas:

- [Si tuvieras que mejorar un aspecto de SO-es, ¿cuál sería?¿Cómo lo mejorarías?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/860/si-tuvieras-que-mejorar-un-aspecto-de-so-es-cu%C3%A1l-ser%C3%ADa-c%C3%B3mo-lo-mejorar%C3%ADas?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [¿Como pedir ayuda para una tarea?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1117/como-pedir-ayuda-para-una-tarea?rq=1)

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo. La mejor estrategia es, en mi opinión, atacar las herramientas que ya usamos, los artículos que todos ya conocemos y mejorarlos.